# Offline Persistence using API REST Firebase and Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, sdk

I am developing an Agro App and when I watched the Firebase promotion videos I really liked the way they describe the application works even when there is no internet (offline persistence).

To develop my App I have used:

- Flutter
- Firebase API REST (http plugin)
- Providers to make requests to the API
- BLOC Pattern

I already have the application practically finished, but I have noticed that when there is no internet an error appears:

> SocketException: Failed host lookup: ‘node1.bitcoiin.com’ (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7)

@IshwarChandra on Medium clarified me:

> When you use offline persistence in Firebase, don't use Transactions
> or await for response.

Is it right? Is it really possible to retrieve data from Firebase without using an await?. I ask this because I have implemented the BLOC pattern in some situations, thus removing the awaits from the user interface. However, behind it always makes a call to a Provider that has awaits to load the data.

On the other hand, a developer at StackOverFlow indicated to me that the Offline Persistence Management can only be done with the Flutter SDK and

> it's NOT possible (or would require too much programming) to implement
> it with the REST API as I have been using it.

Is that statement correct? If so, I have the following doubts:

1. Is there documentation or tips that allows me to easily migrate http REST Firebase API requests (which I have mainly in the Provider) to the Firebase SDK in Flutter?
2. Can I keep the architecture of BLOCs and PROVIDERs that I'm using?
3. Some another tip before to do changes?

For your reference, example code that I have on my Providers:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:aplians_fish/src/preferencias_usuario/preferencias_usuario.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:aplians_fish/src/models/alimentar_model.dart';

class AlimentarProvider {

  final String _url ='https://apliansdb.firebaseio.com';

  final _prefs = new PreferenciasUsuario();


// ==========================================================
// ======================== CREATE ==========================
// ==========================================================

  Future<bool> crearAlimentar(AlimentarModel alimentar, String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {


    final url ='$_url/empresas/$idEmpresa/estanques/$idEstanque/loteActual/alimentacion.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';
   
    final resp = await http.post(url, body: alimentarModelToJson(alimentar));
    final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body); // Da la respuesta, sea un cargue o un error
    print(decodedData);
    return true;
   
  }

// ==========================================================
// ================== READ  =====================
// ==========================================================

  Future<List<AlimentarModel>> cargarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {

    final url ='$_url/empresas/$idEmpresa/estanques/$idEstanque/loteActual/alimentacion.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';
    final resp = await http.get(url);

    final Map<String, dynamic> decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
    final List<AlimentarModel> alimentar = new List();

    if (decodedData == null) return [];
    if (decodedData['error'] != null) return [];

    decodedData.forEach((id, alim){
      final temp = AlimentarModel.fromJson(alim);
      temp.idAlimentar = id;

      alimentar.add(temp);
      
    });

    return alimentar;

  }

// ==========================================================
// =========================== UPDATE =======================
// ==========================================================

  Future<bool> editarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque, AlimentarModel alimentar) async {
    
    final url = '$_url/empresas/$idEmpresa/estanques/$idEstanque/loteActual/alimentacion/${alimentar.idAlimentar}.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';

    final resp = await http.put(url, body: alimentarModelToJson(alimentar));
    final decodedData = json.decode(resp.body);
    print(decodedData);
    return true;

  }

// ==========================================================
// ================== DELETE =======================
// ==========================================================


  Future<bool> borrarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque, String id) async {
    final url = '$_url/empresas/$idEmpresa/estanques/$idEstanque/loteActual/alimentacion/$id.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';
    final resp = await http.delete(url);
    print(json.decode(resp.body));
    return true;
  }


}
```

And, it's the way I'm using BLOC:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:aplians_fish/src/models/alimentar_model.dart';
import 'package:aplians_fish/src/providers/alimentar_provider.dart';


class AlimentarBloc {

  final _alimentarController = new BehaviorSubject<List<AlimentarModel>>();
  final _cargandoController = new BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  final _alimentarProvider = new AlimentarProvider();

  Stream <List<AlimentarModel>>        get alimentarStream    => _alimentarController.stream;
  Stream <bool>                        get cargando           => _cargandoController.stream;


  Future<List<AlimentarModel>> cargarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {
    final alimentar = await _alimentarProvider.cargarAlimentar(idEmpresa, idEstanque);
    // ahora hay que insertar estos productos al stream...
    _alimentarController.sink.add(alimentar);
    return alimentar;
  }

   Future<bool> crearAlimentar(AlimentarModel alimentar, String idEmpresa, String idEstanque) async {
    
    _cargandoController.sink.add(true);
    await _alimentarProvider.crearAlimentar(alimentar, idEmpresa, idEstanque);
    _cargandoController.sink.add(false); //este es útil para bloquear botones cuando se esté cargando
    // esto se hace para notificar que está cargando el producto y de esa forma espere
    return true;

  }


  void editarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque, AlimentarModel alimentar) async {
    
    _cargandoController.sink.add(true);
    await _alimentarProvider.editarAlimentar(idEmpresa, idEstanque, alimentar);
    _cargandoController.sink.add(false);
    // esto se hace para notificar que está cargando el producto y de esa forma espere

  }


  Future<bool> borrarAlimentar(String idEmpresa, String idEstanque, String id) async {
    
    // _cargandoController.sink.add(true);
    await _alimentarProvider.borrarAlimentar(idEmpresa, idEstanque, id);
    // _cargandoController.sink.add(false);
    // no se requieren los controllers porque para la persona al desplazar, siente que ya se borró
    return true;

  }

  dispose() {
    _alimentarController?.close();
    _cargandoController?.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be getting data fro the Firebase Realtime Database through its REST API. The Firebase SDKs implementing client-side caching, but since you're not using the SDKs, you're also not using the caching from the SDK.

To learn how to read from Firebase with the SDK, I recommend reading the Firebase documentation for (for example) [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start), and the [example in the Flutter library](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_database/example). Between those you should be able to figure out a mapping. If you have a problem with a specific piece of your code, post a new question with just that problem.

Using BLoCs is unrelated to whether you use Firebase, so you can keep using them as long as you map the code that interacts with the database from using the REST API to using the Firebase SDK.

Comment: thank you. A last question. In order to support offline persistence, if I change to SDK... Do I really need to stop using the awaits that are in the BLOC?

Comment: The Firebase SDK also retrieves the data from the server asynchronously, so (depending in how you implement it) you may still be awaiting a result or listening to a stream.

Comment: Android Documentation Reference includes Java and Kotlin Examples, but I'm using Flutter / DART. How can I do it?

Comment: As in my answer, I recommend reading the Android documentation to understand the process, and then combining that with Flutter example, and its API reference documentation. If you then have problems on how to map a specific API call, post a new question with that specific problem.

Comment: Ok Frank, thank you, I published in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63102194/how-to-map-an-api-rest-firebase-call-in-flutter-firebase-sdk)